# how to make an API request inside workManager?

Tags: android, kotlin-coroutines, android-workmanager, dagger-hilt

I'm trying to use WorkManager for a periodic to retrieve notifications count from the API, the problem is that I'm using hilt for the dependency injection therefore I can't inject my repository with "@Inject" even if i used @AndroidEnteryPoint. And how I can observe my retrieved data inside the "doWork" function.

```
    class NotificationsCountWorker
    (
    val context: Context,
    workerParams: WorkerParameters) :
    CoroutineWorker(context, workerParams) {


    @Inject lateinit var repo: RepositoryImpl
   
    
    override suspend fun doWork(): Result {
        Log.d(TAG, "doWork")
        //subscribeObserver()
        return try {
            withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
                try {
                    Log.d(TAG, "inside with context")
                    repo.notificationsCount().onEach {
                        Log.d(TAG, "item; $it")
                    }.launchIn(this)
                    Log.d(TAG, "notif count ")
                    Result.success()

                } catch (e: Exception){
                    Log.d(TAG, "exception ${e.message}")
                    Result.failure()
                }
            }
        }catch (e:Exception){
            Log.d(TAG, "exception ${e.message}")
            Result.failure()
        }


}


    companion object {
    private const val TAG = "NotificationsWorkManger"
    const val NOTIFICATIONS_COUNT_WORK_MANGER_ID = "automatic_notifications_count_manger"
    fun reminder() {
        val periodicRefreshRequest = PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(
            NotificationsCountWorker::class.java, // Your worker class
            15, // repeating interval
            TimeUnit.MINUTES
        )

        val periodicWorkRequest: PeriodicWorkRequest = periodicRefreshRequest
            .build()
        WorkManager.getInstance(getApplication()).enqueueUniquePeriodicWork(
            NOTIFICATIONS_COUNT_WORK_MANGER_ID,
            ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.REPLACE,
            periodicWorkRequest
        )
    }
}


}
```

Comment: Are you using the [specific integration between Hilt and WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-jetpack#workmanager)?

Comment: I'm not injecting the work manager I'm trying only to inject the repository inside it, but even when I followed the specific integration it didn't change anything

Comment: What do you think that integration between Hilt and WorkManager does except enable you to inject your repository into your Worker? That's exactly the example in the docs.

Comment: yes I did it after your first message and I followed the documentation but it still the same problem which is lateinit not initiated yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to inject your dependencies through a constructor. In order to enable injection to a Worker with Hilt you need to do the following.

First, annotate your Worker, its constructor and constructor arguments as such:

```
@HiltWorker
class MyWorker @AssistedInject constructor(
    @Assisted context: Context,
    @Assisted workerParameters: WorkerParameters,
    private val repository: Repository
) : CoroutineWorker(context, workerParameters)
```

You should only annotate `context` and `workerParameters` as `@Assisted`. All your other dependencies are resolved by Hilt, they must be installed in `SingletonComponent` or be unscoped.

Then inject `HiltWorkerFactory` to your main `Application`-derived class and make this class implement the `Configuration.Provider` interface like this:

```
@HiltAndroidApp
class MainApplication : Application(), Configuration.Provider {

    @Inject
    lateinit var workerFactory: HiltWorkerFactory

    override fun getWorkManagerConfiguration() =
        Configuration.Builder()
            .setWorkerFactory(workerFactory)
            .build()
}
```

The final step is to disable default WorkManager initialization. To do this, insert these lines to your `AndroidManifest.xml` if you're using WorkManager of version 2.6.0-alpha01 or higher:

```
<provider
    android:name="androidx.startup.InitializationProvider"
    android:authorities=\"${applicationId}.androidx-startup"
    android:exported="false"
    tools:node=\"merge">
    <!-- If you are using androidx.startup to initialize other components -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="androidx.work.impl.WorkManagerInitializer"
        android:value="androidx.startup"
        tools:node="remove" />
</provider>
```

or

```
<!-- If you want to disable android.startup completely. -->
<provider
    android:name="androidx.startup.InitializationProvider"
    android:authorities="${applicationId}.androidx-startup"
    tools:node="remove">
</provider>
```

If you're using older versions, you should add this:

```
<provider
    android:name="androidx.work.impl.WorkManagerInitializer"
    android:authorities="${applicationId}.workmanager-init"
    tools:node="remove" />
```

Comment: Hi, thanks I appreciate your response this what I'm looking for.